# Calculating days to a specific date

Tags: vb.net, datetime

```
Dim intYear, intMonth, intDay As Integer, strResult As String, tspResult As TimeSpan


        intYear = Integer.Parse(txtYear.Text)
        intMonth = Integer.Parse(txtMonth.Text)
        intDay = Integer.Parse(txtDay.Text)

Dim dteDatum As New System.DateTime(intYear, intMonth, intDay)

            tspResult = Now.Subtract(dteDate)
        strResult = Math.Abs(tspResult.Days).ToString
            MessageBox.Show(strResult)
```

For example:
today it is the 1st of october and i want to know how many days till the 4th of october.
The program will say 2days but that's wrong, it must be 3 days.
How can i fix this?
(Calculations in the past are good)
Thanks in advance and sorry if my english sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try use datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
' The following statements set datTim1 to a Thursday
' and datTim2 to the following Tuesday.
Dim datTim1 As Date = #1/4/2001#
Dim datTim2 As Date = #1/9/2001#
' Assume Sunday is specified as first day of the week.
Dim wD As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Weekday, datTim1, datTim2)
Dim wY As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, datTim1, datTim2)
```